# Remove knockout js bindings on cloned element

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using the knockout js template binding functionality to render a collection of items to an element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ko.applyBindings(new function () {
        this.childItems = [{ Text: "Test", ImageUrl: "Images/Image.png" }];
    });
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="template">
    <div class="childItem" data-bind="attr: { title: Text }">
        <img data-bind="attr: { src: ImageUrl }" />
    </div>
</script> 

<div class="childSelector" data-bind="template: { name: 'template', foreach: childItems }">
</div>
```

When clicked, the child items are cloned and placed into another element:

```
$(".childSelector").on("click", ".childItem", function () {
    var clone = $(this).clone()[0];
    ko.cleanNode(clone);
    $(".targetNode").append(clone);
});
```

The problem is that when the source data changes and the template is re-bound to the new data, the following error is thrown:

> Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings. Message: ReferenceError:
>   Text is not defined; Bindings value: attr: { title: Text }

I had found another post that suggested using `ko.cleanNode(element)` to remove knockout's bindings, however this has not resolved the issue in my case.

Is there a way to remove knockout's bindings on a cloned element to prevent this error when re-binding?  If not I'll just "manually" clone the element by extracting the required data from the clicked element.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/QJu5u/) is a simple example of what I'm doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove all knockout bindings from an element by traversing the DOM and removing the `data-bind` attributes and knockout comments.

Use `removeDataBindings(clone);` but first clean the node with `ko.cleanNode(clone)` to clear any event handlers.

```js
var commentNodesHaveTextProperty = document.createComment("test").text === "<!--test-->";
var startCommentRegex = commentNodesHaveTextProperty ? /^<!--\s*ko(?:\s+(.+\s*\:[\s\S]*))?\s*-->$/ : /^\s*ko(?:\s+(.+\s*\:[\s\S]*))?\s*$/;
var endCommentRegex =   commentNodesHaveTextProperty ? /^<!--\s*\/ko\s*-->$/ : /^\s*\/ko\s*$/;

function isStartComment(node) {
    return (node.nodeType == 8) && (commentNodesHaveTextProperty ? node.text : node.nodeValue).match(startCommentRegex);
}

function isEndComment(node) {
    return (node.nodeType == 8) && (commentNodesHaveTextProperty ? node.text : node.nodeValue).match(endCommentRegex);
}

function traverseNode(node, func) {
    func(node);
    node = node.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        traverseNode(node, func);
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
}

function removeDataBindings(element) {
    var koComments = [];

    traverseNode(element, function (node) {
        if (isStartComment(node) || isEndComment(node)) {
            koComments.push(node);
            return;
        }
        //remove the 'data-bind' attributes
        if (node.nodeType === 1) { //ELEMENT_NODE
            node.removeAttribute('data-bind');
        }
    });

    //remove Knockout binding comments
    for (i = 0; i < koComments.length; i++) {
        node = koComments[i];
        if (node.parentNode) {
            node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm taking the advice and not going down my original path, however this answers the question for future visitors!

Answer (score 0):

Oliver, using jQuery to clone elements bound to knockout like this is not a good idea. You should be using data-binding for the `targetNode`. If you haven't yet done so, its a good idea to go through the [Knockout Tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/) to get a good understanding of the basic uses.

If you are trying to keep a list of items, with a clone button, here is a [dead simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/hc6xU/) using nothing but Knockout to do so. If you are trying to do something else, let me know; your question isn't entirely clear on your goal.

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
    <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.clone">Clone</button></br>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var ViewModel = function(data) {
    var self  = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray(data);
    self.clone = function(item) {
        //The ko.toJS here is a handy copy tool for viewModels
        //It isn't necessary for simple arrays like this one
        //But I included it because for an array of objects, you will want to use it
        self.items.push(ko.toJS(item));
    };
};
```

Comment: Hi Tyrsius, see my question for an example, when re-applying the bindings after performing a clone, an error is thrown in the console.  This is the first time that I've used knockout, but thinking about it I could have the destination as an observable array rather than cloning the source items... do you know if there is an answer to the question regarding removing bindings?

Comment: I see the error, did you read my answer? If you are using Knockout, you should not use jQuery for DOM cloning. That role belongs to Knockout.

Comment: Yeah, cleaning the clone isn't the issue in your code. You are actually calling `applyBindings` in the button function. You can't do that, since the original (not the clone) still have bindings on it. You should *never* call `applyBindings` twice; update the bound observables, the nodes will update themselves. You really ought to go through the tutorials.